# jquery: get immediately previous sibling OR parent of element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I have a form with several inputs, and a corresponding label next to them (to the left).

When I validate the inputs, i want to show a message wusing the corresponding label, to tell which input is wrong.

I have a working script showing the labels as I want, but it breaks if my input is not a direct sibling of the label, but a sibling's child instead...

Here is the code to illustrate:

HTML:

```
<form>
<label class="autoFormLabel obligatorio">* calle : </label>
<input id="calle2" class="autoForm obligatorio" type="text" value="" name="calle2">
<br>
<label class="autoFormLabel obligatorio">* CP : </label>
<input id="CP" class="autoForm obligatorio" type="text" value="" name="CP">
<br>
<label id="label_colonia" class="autoFormLabel obligatorio">* Colonia : </label>
<span id="span_combo_colonias">
    <select id="Colonia" class="obligatorio autoForm" name="Colonia">
    <option selected="" value="0">-- seleccione --</option>
        <option  value="1">one</option>
        <option  value="2">two</option>
    </select>
</span>
<br>
<label class="autoFormLabel obligatorio">* Delegacion : </label>
<input id="delegacion" class="autoForm obligatorio" type="text" value="" name="delegacion" >
<br>

    <input type="button" id="val" value="Val" />

</form>
```

JS:

```
function validate(){
    $(":input.obligatorio:enabled").each(function( i, el ){ // solo considerar los enableds            
        if( $(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == "0" || $(this).val() == 0){

            label = $(this).prev("label").html(); //A: works for all but select            
            //label = $(this).parent().prev("label").html(); //B: works for select, but not the others         
            //label = $(this).closest("label").html(); //C: why doesn't work for select?

            alert("El campo:\n\n"+label+"\n\nno puede ir vacio");
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }       
    });
}
```

and here's [a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrehymm/)

all inputs have a corresponding sibling label, except the `<select>`, which is inside a `<span>`, which itself is a sibling of its label.

my selector `label = $(this).prev("label").html();` works perfect for all inputs excpet for the select, because it is contained inside a span (I need it like this because such select is dynamic, and gets inserted inside such span via AJAX)

I know that I could make it work with another selector for the select case, like this: `label = $(this).parent().prev("label").html();`
but ideally I would like to have only one selector to get all the labels, no matter how deep their corresponding input is.

I also tried with the .closest() selector, but it doesn't work, I am not sure why, but I think it doesn't, because the label is not an ascendant of the select (it is a sibling of it's parent, [let's say an 'uncle'])

So which selector could I use for all cases, to get the closest previous label to an input, despite being a parent, a sibling, a parents sibling or even a grand grand grand parent, whatever... (i could have an input buried within several spans next to its label, or whatever)

In other words, how can I traverse the DOM "above and to the left" and get the first ocurrance of a selector, no matter if they are parents OR siblings?

Comment: @nirmal, the fiddle is already there.

Comment: @Nimal the question is complete and clear

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ryankirkman/6630488

Comment: @mplungjan it seems that your solution doesn't work. I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2pu3Lm3/). Maybe I did something wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `for` attribute on your labels:

```
<label for="calle2" class="autoFormLabel obligatorio">* calle : </label>
<input id="calle2" class="autoForm obligatorio" type="text" value="" name="calle2"/>
...
```

Then grab the label text using following jQuery selector:

```
label = $('[for="'+this.id+'"]').html();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrehymm/1/)

---

Jet another way would be to store the "*message*" label in a `data` attribute of the inputs/selects instead of searching for elements within the DOM:

```
<input id="calle2" data-label="Calle" class="autoForm obligatorio" type="text" value="" name="calle2"/>
```

jQuery:

```
label = $(this).attr('data-label');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwrehymm/2/)

Comment: after adding the for to the label. Good idea

Comment: wow! I didn't know the `for` attribute in label elements. In my case, it will definitely work,  However, I still would like to know how to achieve such selections with jQuery. what if I wanted to select other parent/sibling html elements rather than labels? Thanks!

Comment: ...besides, the `for` option wouldn't work if I had one label for several consecutive inputs. However, I could use a dummy attribute on the labels, and add all the corresponding input's id's, and use a slightly different selector, like `$('[dummy~="'+this.id+'"]').html();` . yeah!

Comment: It's something else than your question is about (more complex). Then I'd go another, much simplier way than this. Updated answer.